# WSO2 CEP : Handle complex input JSON objects

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I am currently trying to figure out how I could handle complex data input in the WSO2 CEP. Let's imagine I have an input event data looking like the one below :

```
{
    "item_id":456,
    "user_id":42,
    "documents":[
            {
                "type":"word",
                "name":"ordre de mission"
            },
            {
                "type":"excel",
                "name":"horaires"
            },
            {
                "type":"pdf",
                "name":"facture"
            }
        ]
}
```

In the ideal case, I would like to see this exploded into 3 events, like in the array below :

```
[
    {
        "item_id":456,
        "user_id":42,
        "type":"word",
        "name":"ordre de mission"
    },
    {
        "item_id":456,
        "user_id":42,
        "type":"excel",
        "name":"horaires"
    },
    {
        "item_id":456,
        "user_id":42,
        "type":"pdf",
        "name":"facture"
    }
]
```

I just Can't figure out how to get something like that... I was thinking about reinjecting the `"documents"` array just as it were a separate event, so the CEP would split the array into 3 stream items. But even if I could do that, the item_id and user_id would be lost in the process...
So far, the only thing I am getting, is the documents field turned into a serialized string in my streams, so it seems useless to retrieve actual data contained within it...

The exemple I'm showing here is quite simple against other stuff I would have to manage, with encapsulated objects and array in several layers. So if someone could point me out a general direction about how to handle arrays and objects when these are not the root of the event data or even layered on top of one anothers, it would really help me !

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Input+Mapping+Types#InputMappingTypes-JSONinputmappingJSONInputMapping

Answer (score 0):

you can use Siddhi map extension to extract those child elements[1]. In the execution plan you can use map:createFromJSON(documents) function (according to your stream corresponding attribute is documents) of the map extension to create a map. Then extract corresponding values from their keys.(word,excel etc)Please refer [1]. If you want to output three events from above stream, then you will have to write a custom StreamProcessor. Please refer [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Siddhi+Extensions#SiddhiExtensions-map

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Writing+a+Custom+Stream+Processor+Extension

Comment: Hi dnWick, thanks for your reply. Though I can't see how anything inside Siddhi could resolve my problem... In my receiver, I have an array : the "documents" JSON field. Between the receiver and any execution plan (siddhi), I need to use a stream, and my core problem is exactly that : how can I put arrays and JSON objects in my stream, given that stream fields can only be of base types (int, bool, string, etc.) ?

Comment: So far no, I'm afraid... We are considering to simplify the event contents... But it would be better if the CEP could adapt to the system and not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider things in a more generic way, I'm wondering how to handle Json data since there is no object type, neither arrays in stream attributes...

Maybe my problem here is really wider than it may appear in my question...

Thing is, I simpl don't understand how to handle complex JSON input data he proper way... I cannot find anything about this in the WSO2 Documentation or anywhere else...

Please, let me know if I'm wrong, but the way I see things, if I had to handle an input JSON data like the one below, it would be really hard or even impossible without serious hooks and ugly workarounds..

{
    "reference": "tiers1",
    "emailRecipient": {
        "to": ["john.paeuudey@domain.com"],
        "carbonCopy": [],
        "blindCarbonCopy": []
    }
}

In the example above, how can I store in my streams the contents of the "to" and "carbonCopy" arrays for instance ? If I use string attributes, then the arrays are serialized in the attibutes. This is almost useable, but when writing those attributes in a publisher, being considered as strings, the CEP adds some quotes around them if JSON is specified, for instance.
And that is just one of the aspect of many problems...

So, my question after all, is the WSO2 CEP even designed to manage such complex JSON data ?? Because I really think it is not...